# Longitude and Latitude are not being Assigned to the HiddenFields[updates]

Tags: javascript, asp.net, geocoding

[updates]
I am trying to get the Latitude and Longitude through Geocoding on the backend(.cs) of aspx file when pushing to database. However, HiddenFields are not being assigned any when i tried to console.log inside the Geocode functions, which gives me undefined.

I tried lots of solutions, but none worked or the question ended halfway without any solutions.
I have tried using:
1. Request.Form[Latitude.UniqueID]
2. Using SetTimeOut(on Geocoding function)
3. Using .Value/.Value.toString() of hiddenField at the backend

Unfortunately, none of this worked at all.

Geocoding functions

```
        var hiddenlat = $("#<%= hiddenlat.ClientID %>");
        var hiddenlng = $("#<%= hiddenlng.ClientID %>");

         function getLatLng() {
         ...

        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': "'" + address + "'" }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                console.log("postal code in post.aspx is ", <%= postalcode 
                 %>);
                var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                hiddenlat.val(latitude);
                hiddenlng.val(longitude);
                console.log(hiddenlat.val()); // undefined
                console.log(hiddenlng.val()); // undefined
                var data = { "lat": latitude, "lng": longitude };
              } else {
                console.log('request fail');
            }

        });

        return true;

    }
```

this is the hiddenfields

```
      <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenlat" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenlng" runat="server" />
```

Buttons used for posting

```
         <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" CssClass ="btn btn- 
          success" Text="List" OnClientClick="getLatLng()" 
           OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"/>
```

Backend codes

```
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int lat = Convert.ToInt32(hiddenlat.Value);
        int lng = Convert.ToInt32(hiddenlng.Value);
        ........

          //Pushing of data into database
          uploadDao.listitem(user, date, item, rtype, ptype, paper, metal, 
           batt, elec, weight, desc, add, images[0], images[1], images[2], 
          images[3], unitno, postalcode, qty, district, Convert.ToInt32(lat), 
           Convert.ToInt32(lng));

            Response.Redirect("SellerListing.aspx?user=" + user);
    }
```

[updates]
When i am setting the value of Hiddenfield inside the Geocoding function, the values inside the HiddenFields are Undefined. May i know why is it undefined? I tried Console.log both latitude and Longitude and both returns me a value.

Comment: Hard to reproduce, I see no backend code where you assign value to those HiddenField. Consider adding a better code sample

Comment: @bradbury9 Hi, sorry for the inconvenience. I have updated my backend codes, you can take a look at it.

Comment: You sure you are getting result from `getLatLng()` ? You can check it by logging both of hidden fields value into console.

Comment: @UmairAnwaar yes you are right, the hiddenField is still undefined.

Comment: Include hidden field in the method

Comment: @UmairAnwaar what do you mean include hidden field in the method?

Comment: @UmairAnwaar I have already Declare a variables of both HiddenFields and assign both Lat and Lng using .val().

Comment: first you need to return false from `getLatLng()` method and log the `var latitude=...`  and  `var longitude =...`

Comment: @UmairAnwaar Could you provide me with an example? Im sorry but i really could not get what you are trying to say. I edited to "return false" but i could not get the "log the var latitude=...  and var longitude =..." part

Comment: @UmairAnwaar I have tried but you said but it's still gives me undefined

Answer (score 0):

First you need to test `geocode` function. To test `geocode` is returning `latitude` and `longitude` you need to log it into console like below.

```
function getLatLng(){
    //... your code.
    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

    console.log("Latitude:" + latitude + ' and Longtitude:' + longtitude );


    //Return false in getLatLng()
    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input type="text"  id="txtAddress" />
<input type="button"  value="Get Lat/Long"  id="btnGetLatLong"/>

<asp:Button Text="Save" runat="server" ID="btnSaveOnSever"  OnClick="btnSaveOnSever_Click" />

<asp:HiddenField   runat="server" ID="hdnLat" ClientIDMod="static"/>
<asp:HiddenField   runat="server" ID="hdnLong" ClientIDMod="static" />
```

Javascript

```
    $('#btnGetLatLong').click(function() {

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var address = $('#txtAddress').val();

        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

                $('#hdnLat').val(latitude);
                $('#hdnLong').val(longitude);
                alert("Success");
            } else {
                alert("faild");
            } 
        }); 

    });
```

Server side

```
protected void btnSaveOnSever_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal lat = Convert.ToDecimal(hdnLat.Value);
    decimal lng = Convert.ToDecimal(hdnLong.Value);
    ........

      //Pushing of data into database
      uploadDao.listitem(user, date, item, rtype, ptype, paper, metal,
       batt, elec, weight, desc, add, images[0], images[1], images[2],
      images[3], unitno, postalcode, qty, district, lat,
       lng);

    Response.Redirect("SellerListing.aspx?user=" + user);
}
```